# Manipulate each line of string property using Ant

Tags: string, ant, ant-loadfile

I have a line delimited list of Javascript files that I loaded to a property using `loadfile`.

```
<loadfile property="src-files" srcfile="${manifest.file}"/>
```

I want to wrap each filename in an HTML script tag, so the input:

```
a.js
foo/b.js
foo/z.js
```

becomes:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="foo/b.js"></script>
<script src="foo/z.js"></script>
```

What's the simplest way to do this without using Ant-Contrib, or any other external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<replaceregexp file="${manifest.file}"
               match="(.+)"
               replace="&lt;script src=&quot;\1&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"
               byline="true" />
```

should do the trick.

If you don't want to replace in the manifest file, make a copy first, and replace in the copy. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html for details

Comment: Couple details: 1) this seems to always include an extra line `<script src=""></script>`, so to get around that, I replaced "(.*)" with "(.+)" 2) Angle brackets for the script tags need to be replaced with &lt; and &gt;

Comment: I fixed my answer. Thanks for mentioning these problems.